# LSTM s for accurate IMU values

Tags: lstm

I know that its too computationally expensive but would using a LSTM for getting clean IMU data for long periods a possible solution. I was thinking of using gazebo to get my training data.Make 2 IMU using hector plugins's IMU and magnetometer plugins to get the clean data and add another set of IMU and Magnetometer to get noisy data (the plugin has the potion to introduce noise and drift). Then train a 2 layered LSTM to predict the right values.

Comment: Please make sure to use paragraphs and make your question clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Using LSTM is a good approach. However, LSTM will only learn the noises you have fed it with. So it will be tricky to train them on any noise when you release your IMU data in the wild. Meaning, a good key to the success of your approach is good training dataset.

A paper titled `Learning when to trust distant supervision: An application to
low-resource POS tagging using cross-lingual projection` has done a similar approach on correcting common mistakes on linguistics tagging using LSTM. While the input of your problem is really different, the paper could be a good start for your exploration here. A source code of the paper is published  [here](https://github.com/mengf1/BiLSTM-Debias).